# NUXT3 Error Unexpected token '||=' in MAC and Linux

Tags: macos, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm Create new Nuxt3 App with command `npx nuxi init nuxt-app` in my Mac mini m1
After cd to nuxt-app and run `yarn install` completed.
I Can't run command `yarn dev`

It's throw Error Unexpected token '||='
[image: Error Deatils]

Any One found this Error like me ? what solution you did ?

My error was happened on Official Code Sandbox link from NUXT Official Website too.
[Nuxt3 Official Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/nuxt/starter/tree/v3-codesandbox?file=/app.vue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand how to edit the codeSandbox.

But after some research the sign `||=` is a new operator understand by node.

So your version of node doesn't understand the operator, try to update to the latest (stable) version, it's expected to work after the version >=15.0.

Comment: Node v15 is not a stable version. The latest LTS is 18, if you cannot use this one use v16. Nothing below.

Comment: Here is the documentation for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment#browser_compatibility And here is a nice website: https://www.joshwcomeau.com/operator-lookup/

Comment: Yes, i say that, if he use a version <15 it's expected to not work with ||=

Comment: same happened to me, didn't notice that was on v14, switched to 18 all is good now